# Not able to delete key with RegDBDeletekey using InstallShield

Tags: installshield

I am new to this InstallShield code.
I am trying to delete a key with

> `RegDBDeleteKey("Nrs_Log");`

But was not able to delete and setup is running fine.
Could anyone suggest any other way to delete a registry key.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why a RegDBDeleteKey() might fail. There is not enough info in your post to determine the problem, so I can't even speculate without more information. So here is how to get more information - You need to get the return value of the RegDBDeleteKey() call, so you can find out what is going on.
The below code gets the return value, converts it to a text error, and displays the result.

```
result = RegDBDeleteKey("Nrs_Log");
if(result < 0) then
   SprintfBox(WARNING, "RegDBDelete...", "Failed to delete registry key.\n Error number: %d \n %s", result, FormatMessage(result) );
endif;
```

Once you know the actual error, you should be able to fix the problem or Google it for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below InstallShield InstallScript on how you can delete a given registry hive. If checks whether the registry key exists or not before trying to delete it:

```
function DeleteRegistryKeys(hMSI)
    STRING keyToDelete;
begin
    keyToDelete = "\\SOFTWARE\\MyRegistryHive\\";
    //comment below line if your target root hive is HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE); //Set this if you want to change the registry root to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
    REGDB_OPTIONS = REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY; //Set this only if you want to search WOW64 hive of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE if you've a 32-bit installer running on a 64 bit operating system.

    if (RegDBKeyExist (keyToDelete) > 0) then
        SprintfMsiLog ("registry keys found. Going to delete registry keys");
        if (RegDBDeleteKey (keyToDelete) < 0) then
            SprintfMsiLog ("Failed to delete registry keys.");
        else
            SprintfMsiLog ("Registry keys deleted successfully.");
        endif;
    else
        SprintfMsiLog ("Registry keys not found.");
    endif;
end;
```